# Rails + passenger: intercept and authorize requests for video resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I'd like to prevent hot linking to my video resources, allowing their view only for logged in users.

I did it with a rewrite condition, but it's not accurate enough, so I'd like rails to be able to intercept the request, and giving it back to apache only after authorizing the user.

Is it possible?

I also tried with the send_data method, but I want to serve the video files with an html5 streaming, and I wasn't able to make it work in this way

Comment: Are your videos in the public directory? Wouldn't it be easier to place the videos in an internal directory that your application controller would only have access to?

Comment: it would be easier, but how do I serve them in streaming?

Comment: Try <video id="video" src="video.ogg" autobuffer preload="auto" width="256" height="256">  
</video>

Comment: ok, but what about the controller action?